# JQuery async callback DEAD slow.... any idea why?

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, performance

I am doing my first steps into Ajax with manual jquery - can not say I like it, but it is better than a full page refresh.

I have a trivial edge case. SERIOUSLY trivial.

There is a backend method in the controller to update what we call a bucket that in the test looks like this:

```
public ActionResult BucketUpdate(int bucketNo, string name = null) {
    return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.OK);
}
```

As you can see, it does nothing. The page has some modal dialog and the following code to exeute attached to the form:

```
        $("#form-editor").on("submit", function (event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            var url = $(this).attr("action");
            var formData = $(this).serialize();
            $.ajax({
                url: url,
                type: "POST",
                data: formData,
                error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                    alert(error);
                },
                success: function (resp) {
                    $('#editor').modal('hide');
                }
            })
        });
```

The fields in the form are hand crafted - i.e. they do not contain validation. THere are just 2 fields.

The problem is that this code executes (debug mode in visual studio) SLOW. Like really slow.

The network profiler shows that the post takes 4.19 seconds - which I consider like 4.1 seconds too long for a local call with a payload that is one line, content length 41.

The timings page in the IE debuggers ays.19 seconds for the second "Start" which is indicated as

> Start‎‎: The time from when the request was initially created to when
>   the request is sent.

I am a little at a loss here. Anyone an idea what I do wrong? Page refreshed (normal pages) do not take that long in debugger and I wonder what may contribute to this ajax being so low. Not sure I do something wrong. Can anyone shed some light what may cause this delay?

A validation in current google chrome shows a seriously terrific latency of 37ms. A release version in VS shows tthe same 4.2ish latency... so - is Jquery/Ajax THAT slow in IE 10 (not managed to get that machine updated to 8.1 yet)?

Comment: Are you sure you are pointing to the correct URL? And there seems to be some network issues, can you ping local host?

Comment: Obviously yes - first that is localhost, second the fact that thigns FLY with chrome indicate it is not a dns or so problem. Chrome executes that in less than 40ms.... a factor of 100 faster. Both started from within visual studio.

Comment: It's not a general problem with IE 10, or even IE 8. Do you have any plugins running that are interfering?

Comment: None that I know of. That is why I am pulling that up. I also do not see the issue in other areas. I just wondered whether it may be something on my page code.

Comment: You're debugging in VS while doing this and hosting it locally on the development machine?  Maybe check your RAM and processor and see if something is pegging it.

Comment: Plenty of both and again, Chrome is 100 times faster - and that is the same test on the same machine. Maybe it IS time for a reinstall this weekend ;)

Answer (score 0):

Is this vs2013? If so is it possible that browserlink is somehow causing this? Have u tried using fiddler to see if the calls are different for each browser?